# TextInputLayout password toggle moves text from center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

While using TextInputLayout with `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` EditText text gravity isn't centered well as shown in the photo. Any help?

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and for the text style

```
<style name="editTextStyle">

    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_fields</item>
    <item name="android:padding">15dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: can you paste your code ,what you have done .

Comment: It does that because the toggle icon is allotted the same space a compound drawable in that position would be, and the text is then centered in the remaining space. That simplest solution that comes to mind would be add a transparent compound drawable to the `EditText` on the left side.

Answer (score 7):

Just add transparent drawable to the left side of `EditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password_space"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password_space"
                    android:gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

For transparent drawable you can use whatever you want with `android:width="48dp"`.

Create drawable resource file `@drawable/ic_password_space.xml`.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="1dp"
        android:viewportWidth="1.0"
        android:viewportHeight="1.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M"
        android:fillColor="#0000"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add empty 48dp drawable on **both sides** of the edit text if you hiding passwordToggle when the editText is empty, Otherwise, the cursor would not be in center initially.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password_toggle_space"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_password_toggle_space"
                android:gravity="center" />
```

for creating empty drawable you can add a blank vector **ic_password_toggle_space.xml** file in drawable resources:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="1dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1.0"
    android:viewportHeight="1.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M"
        android:fillColor="#0000"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding left-drawable to inner `EditText` won't take effect (at least as for support lib. v26.1.0).

Adding left-padding to inner `EditText` takes some effect, but contents of `EditText` still won't be centered properly - no matter what value you will use for padding.

The only working solution I found (except subclassing or using 3rd party libs) - is to add negative `drawablePadding` to `EditText`. So in xml it will look like:

```
android:drawablePadding="-48dp"
```

But it is kind of hacky, because implementation of `InputTextLayout` might change in future. So use it at your own risk.